# logical patterns in dictionaries

Tags: r, nlp

could you advice me on some difficult task. Namely find logical patterns in dictionaries. Let's take any dictionary of the any language. There is a word, and it's definition .
For example

The machine is a technical device performing mechanical movements.

In this definition, machine is particular  and  technical device is common.
In essence, particular and common are one of patterns in the dictionary definitions: The first is particular, then goes common.
Is there any method in NLP, which could help me in further discovering any logistic patterns in the dictionary definition?

Comment: `The progammer is sad. The machine is failing.` := it is hard to derive the semantics from *only* the syntax.

Comment: hm, you right notice. What you could me advice to decide this task? maybe you have idea?

Comment: You could start by categorising all semantic meanings of `is ` in `A is B`, or maybe even in `A is a B` , depending on A and B. (but: `the machine is a failure. The programmer is a loser.' ;-)

Comment: how can i create semantic field using any soft (R,Weka, Rapidminer)? is there a way?

Comment: Possibly you could use parts of speech tagging (pos) and remove all but nouns and verbs.  I think openNLP does pos tagging, especially if you use python (or rPithon).  Search on SO for "part of speech".  At least you would reduce your set of terms and relationships in your dictionary.

Comment: Yes, it's too good idea, but my native language not english, but russian and semantics and syntax not such as english.

Comment: Do you want to discover new relation types or new patterns behind specified relation type? Can you provide few more examples?